# How have VS Code/Intellisense recognize glib C/C++ on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, dll, linker, gnu

I am wracking my brain trying to figure out how to have VS Code recognize glib.

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (Q:\code\srctext\text_lexer.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "glibconfig.h" (dependency of "glib-2.0/gmodule.h")C/C++(1696)
```

I have manually built glib and have the following *.dll and *.pdb files:

- gio-2.0-0
- glib-2.0-0
- gmodule-2.0-0
- gobject-2.0-0
- gthread-2.0-0

but I do not know if this is necessary to include when vcpkg has it installed?

I have installed glib using **vcpkg** (`Package glib:x86-windows is already installed`).

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue, did you get this working ?

Comment: I did!  See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what combination of corrections did the trick, but the errors went away when my `c_cpp_properties.json` file looked like below.

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32Debug",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/debug/**",
                "C:/sync/name/code/projects/frameworks/projectA/projectA/include/**",
                "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/include/glib-2.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86",
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": "${default}",
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/include/debug/**",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/projects/frameworks/projectA/projectA/include/debug/**",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/include/glib-2.0"
                ]
            },
            "compilerArgs": [],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "forcedInclude": [
                "${default}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Win64Debug",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/include/debug/**",
                "D:/backup/sync/name/code/projects/frameworks/projectA/projectA/include/debug/**",
                "D:/backup/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "D:/backup/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/include/glib-2.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/include/debug/**",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/projects/frameworks/projectA/projectA/include/debug/**",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                    "C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/include/glib-2.0"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Not sure if `tasks.json` had any influence (frankly Visual Code's inner workings are an opaque impenetrable blob to my attempts at understanding), but just in case:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++ g++.exe build",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "--include-directory=C:/sync/name/code/libraries/c c++/GTK/glib/lib/**"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```